# Is JPanel supposed to be added to a JFrame?

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have this code which I don't understand:

```
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Risultati protocolli cercati");
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel body = new JPanel();
    Container c = jframe.getContentPane();
    body.setSize(100, 100);
    body.setLayout(new GridLayout(1000, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        body.add(new JLabel("JLabel " + i));

    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(body);

    c.add(jsp);
    jframe.setSize(100, 100);
    //jframe.add(body);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
```

If I leave the penultimate line commented then everything appears, both labels and scroll. Instead if I uncomment that line, I see nothing. Only the JFrame. Why does it happens? For the main window of my program I had to perform jframe.add(body)...

Answer (score 2):

> Instead if I uncomment that line, I see nothing. Why does it happens?

The below line

```
jframe.add(body);
```

internally calls

```
jframe.getContentPane().add(body);
```

---

[`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) by default uses [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) and `add(component)` method directly add it in the center section, if you add again then last one is replaced with latest one.

You can use overloaded `add()` method of `JFrame` to add it in another section east, west, north and south as shown in below snapshot:

[image]

for e.g.:

```
frame.add(comp,BorderLayout.NORTH); // add in north section
frame.add(comp,BorderLayout.WEST); // add in west section
```

You can use other [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) as well as per the design or your application:

It's worth reading [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

#### One more suggestion:

Use `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setSize()` that fits the components as per component's preferred size.

Comment: +1, because you don't want to add multiple components to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout, however, it does not solve the mystery of the missing labels. Normally when you add two components to the CENTER, only the second component will be displayed, so the labels should still appear, just without a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem caused by the layout managers.

1. A component can only have a single parent. First you add the "body" to the scrollpane but then the "body" gets removed from the scrollpane when you add it to the content pane of the frame (for the reasons mentioned by @braj). Not a big deal as it just means you won't see any scrollbars.
2. Since the component is directly added to the content pane you should still see the labels however they do not display and this is the confusing part. Change your code to use "100" for the GridLayout and the number of components you create in the loop. When the frame first displays the panel will be empty. Now, increase the height of the frame and you will see the components appear. What is happening is that you are trying to paint too many components in a small area and because of rounding issues the height of every component becomes 0, so there is nothing to paint. When you increase the height to at least 100 pixels every component can now be 1 pixel high so you get garbage.

The only solution is to keep the "body" panel in the scrollpane so that all components will be displayed at their preferred size. Then you can scroll through all the components as required.

A tip for when using a GridLayou. You can use:

```
body.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

Then means the grid will have unlimited rows and a single column.

Comment: Thank to you too. The fact that 0 gives unlimeted rows is very useful to me!